# How to `find` within specific folders without walking present folders in a recursive search?

Tags: bash, shell, find, sh, zsh

In the shell, I have been using the `find` command with arguments such as `-path SomePath` to find files within certain paths, for example:

```
find . -name '*some_pattern*' -path a_subfolder
```

From the time that it takes on folders with large contents, it appears to be walking the entire tree and simply returning only the matches it finds within `a_subfolder`.  This is certainly very undesirable because it spends a large amount of time walking the tree without simply going directly to the paths defined by the `-path` argument.

I could string a few finds together and find in each folder specifically, but I would prefer to have one cohesive `find` command that efficiently walks the defined trees and avoids all superfluous other paths within the current path.

How can you limit `find` to search specifically within the defined paths vs how it seems to currently work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you limit find to search specifically within the defined paths

Just provide predefined path list to find's first argument:

```
find {my/path,another/path,some/path} -name '*some_pattern*'
```

Comment: Good call.  I simply didn't think of globbing it all together on the first path vs using the argument options (as I was used to using the `-not` / `!` arg for exclusions).

Comment: Yes true I have also rarely seen glob use in find's first path.

Answer (score 0):

Search in the `subfolder` for the `some_pattern` without recursion:

```
$ find /path/to/subfolder -maxdepth 1 -name '*some_pattern*'
```